# What is parent:: scope for a trait

Tags: php, php-7

I have a class MyClass that uses trait MyTrait. Both of them have a method getName() (MyClass inherits it from MyParentClass).

What would be the parent scope for MyTrait::getName()? What is the correct way of calling MyClass::getName() and MyParentClass::getName() in MyTrait context?.

See the code below for reference.

```
trait MyTrait {
   public function getName() : string
   { 
       return parent::getName() . '_special';
   }
}

class MyParentClass {
   public function getName(): string
   {
      return "MyName";
   }
}
class MyClass extends MyParentClass {
   use MyTrait;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trait methods act like they are declared in the class using the trait i.e.

```
trait MyTrait {
   public function getName() : string
   {
       return parent::getName() . '_special';
   }
}

class MyClass extends MyParentClass {
   use MyTrait;

}
```

Is functionally the same as

```
class MyClass extends MyParentClass {
   public function getName() : string
   {
       return parent::getName() . '_special';
   }
}
```

It should be clear that in this case `parent` refers to `MyParentClass`. If there's any doubt using the following code:

```
<?php

trait MyTrait {
   public function getName() : string
   {
       return parent::getName() . '_special';
   }
}

class MyParentClass {
   public function getName(): string
   {
      return "MyName";
   }
}
class MyClass extends MyParentClass {
   use MyTrait;

}

$instance = new MyClass();

echo $instance->getName();
```

Produces the following output:

```
MyName_special
```

This can further be tested/demonstrated using `return parent::class;` ([ref](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)) in the trait method, which returns `MyParentClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define a `getName()` method in your subclass. Per the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), the precedent for traits is:

> An inherited member from a base class is overridden by a member inserted by a Trait. The precedence order is that members from the current class override Trait methods, which in turn override inherited methods.

This means that because you do not have a `getName()` method in your subclass, the trait method takes precedence, overriding the parent method. With a `getName()` method in the subclass, it takes precedence.

So you would need to do something like the following, notice the aliasing of the `getName()` method in the trait usage:

```php
trait MyTrait {
    public function getName() : string
    {
        return parent::getName() . '_special';
    }
}

class MyParentClass {
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return "MyName";
    }
}
class MyClass extends MyParentClass {
    use MyTrait {
        MyTrait::getName as getTraitName;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return parent::getName();
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
var_dump($myClass->getName()); //string(6) "MyName"
var_dump($myClass->getTraitName()); //string(14) "MyName_special"
```